# Get the last value of the onChange function

Tags: reactjs, onchange

```js
//let's say these are the 3 variables i got from the text
const varArray = ['montant', 'test','date']

//and here is where i want to store the name of the variable and the value the user typed in the
//text field
const [variableValues, setVariableValues] = useState([{name: '', value: ''}]);

//this is the what i m doing in order to solve the given problem
{
   varArrayCopy.map(
        variable =>
              <TextField
                    key={variable}
                    margin="dense"
                    label={variable}
                    fullWidth
                    variant="standard"
                    onChange={e => setVariableValues([...variableValues, {name: variable, value: e.target.value}])}
               />
   )
}
```

i m sending back the data in an alert (after i click on the "send" button) and the result i m getting is this

[The data i m getting back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsXS3.png)

Answer (score 0):

It appears like that because you used **onChange** prop. Each keystroke renders a change to your **variableValues** state thus adding a object letter by letter. What you can do is use the **useRef** hook for your Text fields in order to get the values. You could create an array named inputRefs which would store these refs & just loop through them through your varArrayCopy.map

```html
const montant = useRef(null);
const test = useRef(null);
const date = useRef(null);

const inputRefs = [montant, test, date]

{
   varArrayCopy.map(
        (variable, index) =>
              <TextField
                    key={variable}
                    margin="dense"
                    label={variable}
                    fullWidth
                    variant="standard"
                    ref={inputRefs[index]}
                    onChange={e => setVariableValues([...variableValues, {name: variable, value: inputRefs[index].current}])}
               />
   )
}
```

Lastly, remove the onChange variable and add the **setVariableValues** to your **Send button** function. Also refactor it like

```html
setVariableValues([...variableValues, {name: variable,value:inputRefs[index].current}
```

This will get the current value inside the text box. Hope this would help brother. Refer to docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

Comment: hey thank u for your answer, in my example i just took the variable "montant" "test" and "date" as static examples, what I really want to do is get any number of variables (any string between 2 dollar signs) in a text written by a user and generate a text field for each one of the variables so the user can type in their values, so i don't think this solution is going to work in my case

Comment: i think i need to add some logic to the onChange function (but i can't really figure out what)

Answer (score 0):

```
    To avoid multiple calls to a function with the onChange property in a 
    React input, debounce or throttle can be used to limit the number of 
    calls to the function.

    In this example, the function handleInputChange will be executed after 
    500 milliseconds after the text input stops. This ensures that the 
    function is executed only once after the text input has stopped.
```

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
    import { debounce } from 'lodash';

    const MyComponent = () => {
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');

    const handleInputChange = debounce((value) => {
    // aquí va la lógica que se ejecutará después del tiempo establecido
    }, 500);

    return (
    <input
      type="text"
      value={inputValue}
      onChange={(event) => {
        setInputValue(event.target.value);
        handleInputChange(event.target.value);
          }}
        />
      );
    };

    export default MyComponent;
```